# vba word variables value delete

Tags: vba, ms-word, docvariable

There is a MS Word 2016 document with DOCVARIABLES set in it. For example:

```
{ DOCVARIABLE "SerialNumber" \* MERGEFORMAT }
```

I need to have this DOCVARIABLE filled in via VBA with InputBox. The VBA code:

```
Sub Document_Open()

Dim sNumber, mNumber, iDate As String

sNumber = InputBox("Please enter the Serial Number", "Serial number", "Enter 
the Serial Number here")

mNumber = InputBox("Please enter the Model Number", "Model number", "Enter 
the Model Number here")

iDate = InputBox("Please enter the Date of Issue, dd.mm.yyyy", "Date of 
Issue", "Enter the Date of Issue here")

With ActiveDocument

  .Variables.Add Name:="SerialNumber", Value:=sNumber

  .Variables.Add Name:="ModelNumber", Value:=mNumber

  .Variables.Add Name:="IssueDate", Value:=iDate

  .Fields.Update

End With

End Sub
```

When the document opens up, it automatically prompts for user data. When the data is entered it then gets populated into DOCVARIABLES within the document. But if I run the code again (when the DOCVARIABLES are storing the data already) it gives me an error: **Run-Time Error "5903": The Variable name already exists.**
The question is how to fix it and make the DOCVARIABLES updatable.

Here is a solution Cindy Meister provided, but with introduction of array:

```
Sub Document_Open()
  Dim sNumber As String, mNumber As String, iDate As String, i As Integer

  Dim varData(1 To 3) As String
    varData(1) = "SerialNumber"
    varData(2) = "ModelNumber"
    varData(3) = "IssueDate"

  Dim varInput(1 To 3) As String
    varInput(1) = InputBox("Please enter the Serial Number", "Serial number", "Enter the Serial Number here")
    varInput(2) = InputBox("Please enter the Model Number", "Model number", "Enter the Model Number here")
    varInput(3) = InputBox("Please enter the Date of Issue, dd.mm.yyyy", "Date of Issue", "Enter the Date of Issue here")


  For i = 1 To 3
  With ActiveDocument
    If DocVarExists(varData(i), ActiveDocument) Then
       .Variables(varData(i)).Value = varInput(i)
    Else
       .Variables.Add Name:=varData(i), Value:=varInput(i)
    End If
   .Fields.Update
  End With
  Next i


End Sub

Function DocVarExists(sVarName As String, doc As Word.Document) As Boolean
    Dim var As Word.Variable, bExists As Boolean
    bExists = False
    For Each var In doc.Variables
        If var.Name = sVarName Then
            bExists = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    DocVarExists = bExists
End Function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With document `Variables` you have two possibilities.

The "simple" one is to simply assign the value. There's no need to use the `Add` method at all. So you need only one line of code, whether the `Variable` already exists in the document or not:

```
ActiveDocument.Variables("name").Value = "new value"
```

(Note: `Variables` originate from the old, Word Basic days, where things were much less formal than they've become. A `CustomDocumentProperty`, in contrast, requires an `Add` method - the object was introduced in the VBA days.)

If you want things to be very correct, then you'd need to loop through the `Variables` collection to find out if it already exists and only add it if it does. I have a little function for this which I've pasted below and put a call to it in your code. (Which I've edited for only one `Variable` to make it easier to follow the function call.)

```
Sub Document_Open()
  Dim sNumber as String, mNumber As String, iDate As String

  sNumber = InputBox("Please enter the Serial Number", "Serial number", _
    "Enter the Serial Number here")

  With ActiveDocument
    If DocVarExists("SerialNumber", ActiveDocument) Then
       .Variables("SerialNumber").Value = sNumber
    Else
       .Variables.Add Name:="SerialNumber", Value:=sNumber
    End If
   .Fields.Update   
  End With   
End Sub

Function DocVarExists(sVarName As String, doc As Word.Document) As Boolean
    Dim var As Word.Variable, bExists As Boolean
    bExists = False
    For Each var In doc.Variables
        If var.Name = sVarName Then
            bExists = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    DocVarExists = bExists
End Function
```

(Note: This is the approach *required* for `CustomDocumentProperties`.)

Just a remark about `Variable` objects for anyone reading this that's not familiar with them: As soon as an emtpy (zero-length) string is assigned the `Variable` object is deleted and no longer available in the document.

Comment: I am going to test your solution tomorrow and give it a feedback. Thanks for the quick reply!